# How can I make "jconsole" work with Websphere 6.1?

Tags: java, websphere, jmx, mbeans

I've deployed some Managed Beans on WebSphere 6.1 and I've managed to invoke them through a standalone client, but when I try to use the application "jconsole" distributed with the standard JDK can can't make it works.

Has anyone achieved to connect the jconsole with WAS 6.1?

IBM WebSphere 6.1 it's supossed to support JSR 160 JavaTM Management Extensions (JMX) Remote API. Furthermore, it uses the MX4J implementation (http://mx4j.sourceforge.net). But I can't make it works with neither "jconsole" nor "MC4J".

I have the Classpath and the JAVA_HOME correctly setted, so the issue it's not there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357095/how-do-you-enable-jmx-in-websphere#358814

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSphere's support for JMX is crap.  Particularly, if you need to connect to any secured JMX beans.  Here's an interesting tidbit, their own implementation of jConsole will not connect to their own JVM.  I have had a PMR open with IBM for over a year to fix this issue, and have gotten nothing but the runaround.  They clearly don't want to fix this issue.

The only way I have been able to invoke remote secured JMX beans hosted on WebSphere has been to implement a client using the "WebSphere application client".  This is basically a stripped down app server used for stuff like this.

Open a PMR with IBM.  Perhaps if more people report this issue, they will actually fix it.

> **Update:** You can run your application as a WebSphere Application Client in RAD.  Open the run menu, then choose "Run...".  In the dialog that opens, towards the bottom on the left hand side, you will see "WebSphere v6.1 Application Client".  I'm not sure how to start and Application Client outside of RAD.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. for WASCE 2.1.1.1

Comment: This really sucks, I have been trying to do this as well.  The Performance tools with Websphere also don't work very well.   Meaning, they don't run.  I think we are expected not to actually performance test/jmx websphere.

Answer (score 1):

IT WORKS !

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-4534;jsessionid=FB20DD5973F01DD2D470FB9A1B45D209?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

```
  1) Change the config.xml and start the server.
```

-see here how to change config.xml: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.0/en/working-with-jconsole.html

```
 2) start the jconsole with : jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%GERONIMO_HOME%\var\security\keystores\geronimo-default -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%GERONIMO_HOME%\var\security\keystores\geronimo-default -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=secret -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%GERONIMO_HOME%\repository\org\apache\geronimo\framework\geronimo-kernel\2.1.4\geronimo-kernel-2.1.4.jar
```

[or your version of geronimo-kernel jar]

```
 3) in the jconsole interface->advanced, input:
  JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/JMXSecureConnector
  user name: system
  password: manager

 4) click the connect button.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the WebSphere MBeans this one works for me:

The key is to configure the classpath and the security properly.

in one line:

jconsole -J-Dwas.install.root=C:/was61 -J-Djava.ext.dirs=C:/was61/plugins;C:/was61/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto_6.1.0;C:/was61/lib;C:/was61/java/jre/lib/ext -J-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL="file:../../properties/ssl.client.props" -J-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL="file:../../properties/sas.client.props" service:jmx:iiop://host:port/jndi/JMXConnector

where port = bootstrap port ex: (2809)

Be careful when setting the sas and the ssl props.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully connected to ActiveMQ and ServiceMix using the JConsole. Does WAS 6.1 use Java Management Extension (JMX) technology? JMX is required for JConsole.

If your path is set correctly it should work fine. On windows you go to System Properties -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables. Have your JAVA_HOME System variable set to the path of your JDK or JRE and your Path variable with %JAVA_HOME%/bin added somewhere in there. Then all you need to do is go to Start->Run->JConsole. Select the correct Process Name and your done.

Where are you having problems at? I hope this helps.

Edit:
Here is the Java Doc's on [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I know that WebSphere is kind of hard to configure. Thats part of the reason we used ServiceMix for our ESB. Maybe its not enabled by default in WebSphere and you would have to turn it on in the config somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere 6.1 does not support the JConsole for some reason even though it fully implements the JMS specs. Seems to be a week area at the moment. Your best bet is to look at the Admin client to implement you own console.

Answer (score 0):

You all seem to be incorrect.  I am running Websphere 6.1.041 , using JDK 1.5 , and I just started up Jconsole and used the "simple connect" tab to connect to localhost with port=0 and without a username and password and it works fine.