# How do you enable JMX in Websphere?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jmx, jconsole

I would like to use JConsole to monitor my Websphere application, but I am not sure how to enable JMX.

Answer (score 33):

Following information is for Websphere 6.1 on Windows.

First of all, the magic URL to connect to the MBean server is:

```
service:jmx:iiop://<host>:<port>/jndi/JMXConnector
```

If you have a default Websphere installation, the JNDI port number will likely be 2809, 2810, ... depending on how many servers there are installed on one system and the specific one you want to connect to. To be sure, when starting Websphere, check the logs, as it will dump a line like

```
0000000a RMIConnectorC A   ADMC0026I: The RMI Connector is available at port 2810
```

If you don't get this line, open the Websphere admin console and go to

> Application servers > server1 >
>   Administration Services > JMX
>   connectors

to see if you need to add or change the config.

Second important bit of information is that the following JAR is always needed when doing JMX with the server:

```
com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar
```

You can find this JAR in the the `runtimes` directory of Websphere. Whatever you do, whether programmatically accessing MBeans on Websphere, or using JConsole, and so on, use the magic URL and **always** include this JAR.

For the remainder of this answer, assume that Websphere is installed in D:\prog\was61.

To run JConsole, type in the following:

```
D:\prog\was61\java\bin>jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=d:\prog\was61\java\lib\tools.jar;D:\prog\was61\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar
```

Then go to the "Advanced" tab and type in the magic JMX URL. Press connect and you should see the MBeans appear.

Using a Sun JDK is an entirely different matter. You need one extra JAR that is in the lib of the IBM JDK but not Sun's (ibmorb.jar), and maybe the following command may work for you:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_11\bin>jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_11\lib\jconsole.jar";"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_11\lib\tools.jar";D:\prog\was61\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar;D:\prog\was61\java\jre\lib\ibmorb.jar
```

I say maybe, because it didn't work for me. I got a nice jndiUnavailCommErr error message, since it expected something on port 2809 while my Websphere installation is listening on 2810, although I correctly specified port 2810 in the JMX URL. But, if you adapt the paths to point to your Sun JDK, it might work for you. It's the closest I ever got to connecting to Websphere using Sun's JDK.

Final note: I tried a solution based on RMI, there is also a SOAP connector available but haven't tried it.

As always with J2EE, Websphere and stuff: good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: +1 worked like a charm. I am sorry for the pain you must have gone through :)

Comment: +1 for the "good luck, you'll need it"... BTW, I have the tree with the object but I can't see the properties because of ADMN0022E (missing rights or something like that) Any idea ?

Comment: You might have to add `jconsole.jar` to the classpath also with the IBM jconsole.

Comment: The 'magic URL' `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` worked for me

Comment: I did all of this, still didn't work.  I got the MBeans tab but not the memory.

Answer (score 9):

It is simple. Just start Websphere with the following JMX parameters:

```
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

Then start JConsole or VisualVM and connect to localhost:1099

Since i am not allowed to post a proof screenshot i post the information from the visualvm "overview tab".

```
PID: 12568
Host: localhost
Main class: <unknown>
Arguments: <none>
JVM: IBM J9 VM (2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32 j9vmwi3223-20100808 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20100629_60535_lHdSMr
JIT - 20100623_16197_r8
GC - 20100211_AA)
Java: version 1.5.0, vendor IBM Corporation
Java Home: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre
JVM Flags: <none>
Heap dump on OOME: disabled
```

Comment: this sort of worked for me, i had to add these same parameters in the websphere console under `Servers/Application servers/server1/Java y gestión de procesos/Definición de proceso/Máquina virtual Java/Argumentos de JVM genéricos` (sorry this is in spanish, i prefer the english version too, but someone at ibm must ve thought we native spanish speakers would prefer a godawful translation). hope this helps someone anyway

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. I tried it by adding those params to the D_ARGS option in the startServer.sh file . Then, connected on 1099 and it only shows data for the websphere admin process and does not show information for the contained application process.

Comment: Makes sense that it wouldn't work because WebSphere runs on a IBM JDK and therefore packages in com.sun.* don't exist, right?

Comment: worked for me ... please note that after *-Djavax.management.builder.initial=* add SPACE

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's a little offtopic, but I have found a way to connect to WAS 7.0 JMX server from JConsole.
No server setup is required, no AppClient, only some JARs and a little client setup.

Use the following script

```
@echo off 
set HOST=<host>
set PORT=2809

set WAS_HOME=D:/Programy/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer

set THIS_DIR=E:/Home/Bogus/Pulpit

set CLIENTSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/%THIS_DIR%/sas.client.props
set PROVIDER=-Djava.naming.provider.url=corbaname:iiop:%HOST%:%PORT% 

set PROPS=
set PROPS=%PROPS% %CLIENTSAS%
set PROPS=%PROPS% %PROVIDER%

set CLASSPATH=
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\java\lib\tools.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\java\lib\jconsole.jar

set URL=service:jmx:iiop://%HOST%:%PORT%/jndi/JMXConnector

@echo on

:: %WAS_HOME%\java\bin\
java -classpath %CLASSPATH% %PROPS% sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole %URL%
```

If the target server has administrative security disabled, comment out CLIENTSAS and PROVIDER lines.

If the security is enabled, you will also need sas.client.props file to be put in THIS_DIR directory. The template file can be found under WAS_profile\properties directory. You will have to do a little setup. Here is an excerpt from my sas.client.props

```
com.ibm.CORBA.securityEnabled=true

com.ibm.CORBA.authenticationTarget=BasicAuth
com.ibm.CORBA.authenticationRetryEnabled=true
com.ibm.CORBA.authenticationRetryCount=3
com.ibm.CORBA.validateBasicAuth=true
com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost=
com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerPort=
com.ibm.CORBA.loginTimeout=300
com.ibm.CORBA.loginSource=prompt

com.ibm.CORBA.loginUserid=
com.ibm.CORBA.loginPassword=

com.ibm.CORBA.krb5ConfigFile=
com.ibm.CORBA.krb5CcacheFile=

com.ibm.CSI.performStateful=true

com.ibm.CSI.performClientAuthenticationRequired=false
com.ibm.CSI.performClientAuthenticationSupported=true

# SET ALL THE FOLLOWING VALUES TO FALSE

com.ibm.CSI.performTLClientAuthenticationRequired=false
com.ibm.CSI.performTLClientAuthenticationSupported=false

com.ibm.CSI.performTransportAssocSSLTLSRequired=false
com.ibm.CSI.performTransportAssocSSLTLSSupported=false

com.ibm.CSI.performMessageIntegrityRequired=false
com.ibm.CSI.performMessageIntegritySupported=false

com.ibm.CSI.performMessageConfidentialityRequired=false
com.ibm.CSI.performMessageConfidentialitySupported=false

# COMMENT THIS OUT
#com.ibm.ssl.alias=DefaultSSLSettings


com.ibm.CORBA.requestTimeout=180
```

OK :)

After connecting, the login popup will appear. Type your admin user and password (user & pw are not required on the connection dialog in JConsole)

You may run the JConsole from IBM JDK, or Sun JDK. For IBM, no other setup is required. However, for Sun you may need to put orb.properties file in your home directory. The file can be found in com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get this to work. All I got was

> The connection to username@service:jmx:iiop//localhost:2809/jndi/JMXConnector did not succeed. Would you like to try again?

I did however get it working by doing the following:

1. Add "-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" to the Generic JVM Argument.
2. Add these lines to WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/management/management.properties

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

But none of the usefull mbeans show up..?

Comment: @Tommy - did you get the "interesting" stuff somehow? I mean without the whole extra jars/IIOP mumbo-jumbo...

Comment: @Chris No, never got it to work like I wanted. Ended up using the PMI servlet that comes with WAS then parsing the xml and graphing it with Munin. Works fine

Answer (score 4):

I found that in order to connect to WAS 6.1 using the Sun JDK JConsole, in addition to the `com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar` JAR file, I had to also include the following 3 JARs on the boot class path when starting JConsole:-

```
ibmorbapi.jar
ibmorb.jar
ibmcfw.jar
```

These can be found in the java\jre\lib directory of websphere.

For example on windows, if you copy all the four JARs listed above to a directory of your choice (i've copied them to C:\packages\was61-jmx in the example below), you can use a batch file like the following to start JConsole:-

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.5.0_20
set WAS6.1_JARS=C:\packages\was61-jmx

set BOOTJARS=%WAS6.1_JARS%\ibmorbapi.jar
set BOOTJARS=%BOOTJARS%;%WAS6.1_JARS%\ibmorb.jar
set BOOTJARS=%BOOTJARS%;%WAS6.1_JARS%\ibmcfw.jar

set CLASSPATH=%WAS6.1_JARS%\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar


%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jconsole  -J-Xbootclasspath/p:%BOOTJARS% -J-Djava.class.path=%CLASSPATH%
```

This worked for me for jdk 1.5 and 1.6 versions of the Sun Jconsole.

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled for a few hours to get this to work and I found the solution. The key issue is here is SSL - the client has to use the proper keys to establish a SSL connection to the server. This involves pointing to the correct trust store location and trust store password as described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wxsinfo/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.admin.doc/cxsjmxsec.html). The best way to set up the environment is to call the setupCmdLine.sh (on Windoze it is setupCmdLine.bat) for the relevant server, and then invoke jconsole like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

WAS_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer

# setup server-specific env variables
. $WAS_HOME/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/setupCmdLine.sh

HOST=localhost
PORT=9100

CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole \
    -J-Djava.class.path=$CLASSPATH\
    -J$CLIENTSAS\
    -J$CLIENTSSL\
    service:jmx:iiop://$HOST:$PORT/jndi/JMXConnector
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the required system properties through the WAS console, because it does not allow you specify empty values. Instead, you have to insert the following at the bottom of 'server.xml':

```
<systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1315391623828" name="com.sun.management.jmxremote" value="" required="false"/>    <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1315327918140" name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.port" value="1235" required="false"/>
<systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1315327935281" name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate" value="false" required="false"/>
<systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1315327948046" name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl" value="false" required="false"/>
<systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1315390852859" name="javax.management.builder.initial" value="" required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

from http://malliktalksjava.in/2010/07/26/enable-jmx-remote-port-in-websphere/

1. Login to *Admin console* of the web sphere any profile(server), short cut will be available in start menu programs.

   - Deploy the **PerfServletApp.ear** application if not deployed already.
   - Check if **PerfServletApp.ear** is deployed:

     - Exapnd **Applications** +> **Application Types** +> **WebSphere Enterpise Applications**
     - If not, click **New Application**.
   - Browse from **WebSphere directory** -> **AppServer** -> **InstallableApps**.
   - *(FOLLOW THE STEPS.)*
2. Enable the PMI Data and set all the statistics enabled.

   - In left pane (bottom), go to **Monitoring and Tuning** +> **Performance Monitoring Infrastructure(PMI)**
   - In *Configuration* tab, enable the **PMI**.
   - In this *Configuration* tab, and the *Runtime* tab, set **All statistics**. Then **Save** changes.
3. Set JVM argument

   - In **Severs** +> **Server Types** +> **WebSphere Application Servers**, then -> **[server-name]** +> **Process definition** -> **Java Virtual Machine**
   - Set the generic jvm argument to include

     > `-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`

   in shows the servers list. click on the server you want.

   - In the right pane -> **Server Infrastructure** -> **Java and Process Management**  click on **Process** definition, again in Additional Properties of **Configuration** tab
     click on **Java Virtual Machine**. put the `-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` in *Generic Jvm Argument* field
     and **save** changes.
4. To enable the JMX remote port open the following properties file and add the code that follows.
   In *[WebSphere-directory]\AppServer\java\jre\lib\management\management.properties*, add:

   ```
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   ```
5. Save the master data, stop the server, and start the server to load the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following [simple method to connect jconsole to Websphere 6.1](http://www.interface101.org/iblog/post/JConsole-on-WAS-61.aspx)

It does works for me (Solaris, Was 6.1, Sun JVM), it also works with Visual VM

Enjoy !

Comment: Can you still access the WebSphere JMX beans with this solution, to get information about servlets and connection pools?

Comment: Link is here and the method works: http://www.ecovations.de/blog/?p=99 . Can't connect from a remote jconsole though... not sure why.  Local console only.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the correct port to connect to on the WebSphere Application Server under Communications -> Ports.  The port associated with BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS allows you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following, it uses the SOAP protocol adapter. I think it's as lean a configuration possible.

```
#!/bin/sh 
current_dir=`dirname "$0"`

HOSTNAME=host.fqdn
PORT=2809

WAS_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
WAS_PROFILE=$WAS_HOME/profiles/AppSrv01
WAS_RUNTIMES=$WAS_HOME/runtimes

WAS_LIB=$WAS_HOME/java/lib
JAVA_HOME=$WAS_HOME/java



CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:$WAS_RUNTIMES/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar:$WAS_LIB/ibmcfw.jar 

TARGET=service:jmx:soap://$HOSTNAME:$PORT/jndi/JMXConnector

CP="-J-Djava.class.path=$CLASSPATH"
SSL_SERVER_KEY="-J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$WAS_PROFILE/etc/DummyServerKeyFile.jks -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=WebAS"
SSL_TRUST_STORE="-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$WAS_PROFILE/etc/DummyServerTrustFile.jks -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=WebAS"
SSL_OPTS="-J-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:$WAS_PROFILE/properties/ssl.client.props"
SOAP_OPTS="-J-Dcom.ibm.SOAP.ConfigURL=file:$WAS_PROFILE/properties/soap.client.props"
WAS_OPTS="-J-Dwas.install.root=$WAS_HOME -J-Djava.ext.dirs=$WAS_HOME/plugins:$WAS_HOME/lib:$WAS_HOME/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto_6.1.0:$WAS_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext"

COMMAND="$JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole $CP $SSL_SERVER_KEY $SSL_TRUST_STORE $SSL_OPTS $SOAP_OPTS $WAS_OPTS $TARGET"

exec $COMMAND
```

Credits to my colleague Jeroen for the initial version of the script using IIOP (I'm trying SOAP in the hope that it will work with Hyperic)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There are two ways to do this:
one using SOAP connector
one using RMi/IIOP connector.

For SOAP you need to do WAS setup to add a new PORT and other JVM args described above. But all you get once JConsole connects to the server are basic JVM metrics.

With RMI you get everything that WebSphere exposes. All the MBeans!
The only caveat is: if your WAS JVM is behind a firewall - you'd need to open a port to get to it from your desktop. But you can run this via X11 right off the app server host!

I used JDK7 on my Windows XP desktop to connect to WAS 7.0 with global security enabled.
I took a script from Answer #4 above and used it as a starting point.
Here's my version of it:

```
@echo off 
set HOST=<put hostname here>
set PORT=<put JVM's BOOTSTRAP_PORT here>

set WAS_HOME=C:\jconsole
set JAVA_HOME=C:\glassfish3\jdk7
set PROPS_DIR=C:\jconsole\properties

set CLIENTSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/%PROPS_DIR%/sas.client.props
set CLIENTSSL=-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/%PROPS_DIR%/ssl.client.props
set PROVIDER=-Djava.naming.provider.url=corbaname:iiop:%HOST%:%PORT% 

set PROPS=
set PROPS=%PROPS% %CLIENTSAS% %CLIENTSSL% %PROVIDER%

set CLASSPATH=
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

set URL=service:jmx:iiop://%HOST%:%PORT%/jndi/JMXConnector

@echo on

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %CLASSPATH% %PROPS% sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole %URL%
```

The WAS_HOME is just a directory where i have those IBM JARs that i downloaded from my WebSphere binaries (off Solaris). I also created two subdirs under there: **properties** and **keystore**.
In the properties subdir i put my sas.client.props and ssl.client.props, also downloaded from a working WAS7 cell (i took it off of a DM).
In the keystore subdir i put the key.p12 and trust.p12 files, also downloaded from a WAS7 cell. Make sure they have the right certs! If the ones from WAS/etc don't work - try the ones from ${CONFIG_ROOT}/cells/.
**Modify ssl.client.props to make sure the path to the p12 files is correct!**

Now, in order for this to work you also have to download the following from your WAS binaries:

```
WAS_BIN_HOME/java/jre/lib/endorsed
```

Put this whole directory under your SUN JDK's **jre/lib** directory. This takes care of the IBM JSSE2 Provider errors and such.
Also, get the following three files from **WAS_BIN_HOME/java/jre/lib/security**:

```
java.security
local_policy.jar
US_export_policy.jar
```

I just overwrote the ones that came with SUN's JDK with the ones i took from IBM's.

Also, in **sas.client.props** be sure to enter user ID and password, similar to how you do it in soap.client.props. You can encode the password the same way. This is needed to get past Global Security's BasicAuth.

I think that's it.
P.S. I'm not a Windows pro, so if there's a cleaner way to do this - please share it.