# Java Error when Configuring Jconsole in WebSphere 6.1

Tags: websphere, jconsole

I have reviewed the previous Jconsole/WAS questions but I need some additional help. When I try and run my script to launch jconsole with Websphere 6.1 (Security enabled) I get this error:
The java class is not found:  sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole

This is the script I am running:

echo off
set HOST=localhost
set PORT=13620

export WAS_HOME=/platform/fi60056/WebSphere

export THIS_DIR=/tmp/steve

export CLIENTSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/$THIS_DIR/sas.client.props
export PROVIDER=-Djava.naming.provider.url=corbaname:iiop:$HOST:$PORT

export PROPS=
export PROPS=$PROPS$CLIENTSAS
export PROPS=$PROPS$PROVIDER

export CLASSPATH=
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH$WAS_HOME/java/lib/tools.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH$WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH$WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_6.1.0.jar

export URL=service:jmx:iiop://$HOST:$PORT/jndi/JMXConnector

echo on

$WAS_HOME/java/bin/java -classpath $CLASSPATH $PROPS sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole $URL

Do you have any ideas of what I am missing?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this thread

[How do you enable JMX in Websphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357095/how-do-you-enable-jmx-in-websphere#358814)  for information on how to get JConsole working with WAS 6.x.

Officially IBM does not support JConsole with WAS 6.x.

HTH
Manglu