# Connecting websphere 7 Using JConsole

Tags: jconsole

Can someone help me for resolving the below issue with JConsole & Websphere&7
I was trying to connect to Websphere 7 using JConsole. However JConsole wasn't able to connect to Websphere 7.

I did following changes - 
1) management.properties
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
2) set the management.properties file path in JVM generic arguments.

Regards,
SR

Comment: What JVM version/vendor are you running? Are you running JConsole on a remote machine or locally on the Websphere 7 server? Have you been able to confirm that the remote management port is open using lsof or netstat?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the WebSphere MBeans this one works for me:

The key is to configure the classpath and the security properly.

in one line:

jconsole -J-Dwas.install.root=C:/was61 -J-Djava.ext.dirs=C:/was61/plugins;C:/was61/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto_6.1.0;C:/was61/lib;C:/was61/java/jre/lib/ext -J-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL="file:../../properties/ssl.client.props" -J-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL="file:../../properties/sas.client.props" service:jmx:iiop://host:port/jndi/JMXConnector

where port = bootstrap port ex: (2809)

Be careful when setting the sas and the ssl props.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

This answer in another question worked for me: [How do you enable JMX in Websphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357095/how-do-you-enable-jmx-in-websphere/1172326#1172326)

However, that only allows access to the Platform MBeans, not the WebSphere MBeans.