# Monitoring WebSphere JVMs

Tags: jvm, websphere, monitor

In order to monitor any normal Java process JVM, we can use the Attach API. Is there an API  available to monitor a WebSphere JVM ?

Comment: websphere should have (depending on version) JMX support. So if it's application monitoring, you should look at those. If you need to monitor at a system level (monitor the VM), you can simply attach to that.

Comment: I heard that WebSphere programs wont allow you to look into their VMs and that is what i want to do.

Comment: well, since it runs on a VM, you could just attach to that, have you tried this ?

Comment: I had my code ready that attaches to a VM and gathers data . But when i try to attach to WebSphere process, it says attach not supported/could not open MBeanServerConnection to the process.

Comment: so you are using JMX.... Look into WebSphere specifics (e.g. starting JMX agent in WebSphere, configuring credentials and the likes of) check this Question here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357095/how-do-you-enable-jmx-in-websphere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use PMI (Performance Monitoring Infrastructure) to monitor both JVM and Java EE related metrics. PMI monitoring data my me accessed using

- Tivoli Performace Viewer which is embedded in administrative console
- PMI client (deprecated)
- PerfServlet (if you don't want to use JMX, this servlet presents same info with XML over HTTP)
- JMX Interface to PMI

You may find following page helpful since you intend to use JMX, as it contains sample code for implementing a JMX client to access PMI data;

[Developing your own monitoring applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tprf_pmi.html)

You may find information about other methods at monitoring section of Infocenter.